# How can I use C-style macros with C++11-style constructor calls?

Tags: c++11, c-preprocessor

I've found what seems to be an incompatibility between using C-style macros and using the new unified list-initialization form introduced in C++11, but it seems incredible that this sort of thing would be absolutely impossible to write, so I assume I'm missing something.

Here's the issue: curly brackets seem to be ignored when the preprocessor looks to find a macros arguments.  A call like `MACR(Range{2,4})` is misinterpreted as having two arguments, `Range{2` and `4`.  In the following code, it's all good (well, poor style, but it works) until the marked line:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Range { int st, fn; };
ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const Range& r)
{ return out << "(" << r.st << "," << r.fn << ")"; }

#define COUT(X) (cout << (X) << endl)

int main()
{
  COUT(3);
  Range r {3,5};
  COUT(r);

  COUT(Range{3,5});  //this line won't compile
}
```

It gives the following error message:

```
badmacro.cpp:16:18: error: macro "COUT" passed 2 arguments, but takes just 1
   COUT(Range{3,5});
                  ^
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
```

Especially when working with older libraries, it's sometimes unavoidable to use macro calls; surely we're not supposed to forgo the new syntax in those cases?  Is there an official workaround for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to pass an expression to an existing macro, and an expression contains unshielded commas, just enclose the whole expression in parentheses.

```
COUT((Range{3,5}));
```

Ugly? Yes, but that's what happens when you are using macros. Don't do that.

If it's not an expression and can't take extra parentheses, then you simply can't use that macro.

If you are writing a macro, which you shouldn't, sometimes you can write a variadic macro (if your compiler supports that):

```
#define COUT(...) cout << (__VA_ARGS__) << endl;
```

Comment: @RemyLabeau a C++11 compiler ought to support that.

Comment: Variadic macros were introduced in C99 before C++11.  Not everyone is using a C++11 compiler yet, and not all pre-C++11 compilers support variadic macros (some do).

Comment: "If it's not an expression and can't take extra parentheses" then it can still be made to work. For this particular instance, `#define ID(...) __VA_ARGS__`, and then `COUT(ID(Range{3,5}))`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau This style of initialisation is new in C++11 and already requires a C++11 compiler. If a C++11 compiler is already required, you might as well make use of it.

Answer (score 2):

Preprocessor macros are just fancy text replacements prior to compiling.  When calling a macro, the preprocessor does very little parsing of the parameter list.  There is some logic to differentiate between commas inside of nested parenthesis versus outside, so it knows which commas belong to the parameter list of the macro itself versus commas for the parameter list of a nested function call. For example:

```
macro(param1, param2, func(param1, param2) )
```

The parameters are interpreted as

```
param1
param2
func(param1, param2)
```

Rather than

```
param1
param2
func(param1
param2)
```

In your case, your comma is not inside of nested parenthesis, so the preprocessor ends up splitting the parameter list `Range{3,5}` into two parameter values

```
Range{3
5}
```

Hence the error because your macro only accepts one parameter.  The preprocessor does not have any context information to know that `Range{3,5}` should be treated as one parameter value.  It just sees the comma and splits on it.

So, to solve your problem, try adding an extra pair of parenthesis:

```
COUT((Range{3,5}));
```

The preprocessor should then interpret one parameter value:

```
(Range{3,5})
```

Which will create the following statement for the compiler to consume:

```
(cout << ((Range{3,5})) << endl);
```